# How to write Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx

I have nginx on Ubuntu

I would like to serve some pages as follows :

- Case A : When a URL starts with ORDS (case insensitive), the following url should be served : **localhost:8443/ords**
- Case B : Otherwise, the following url should be served : **localhost:8443/something:**

For example Case A :

- **[www.example.com/ords](http://www.example.com/ords)**    >>>> **localhost:8443/ords**
- **[www.example.com/ordsXXX](http://www.example.com/ordsXXX)**    >>>> **localhost:8443/ordsXXX**
- **[www.example.com/ords/XXX](http://www.example.com/ords/XXX)**   >>>> **localhost:8443/ords/XXX**
- **[www.example.com/ORDS/XXX](http://www.example.com/ORDS/XXX)**   >>>> **localhost:8443/ords/XXX**

and Case B

- **[www.example.com/XXX](http://www.example.com/XXX)**        >>>> **localhost:8443/ords/something:XXX**
- **[www.example.com/XXX?whatever](http://www.example.com/XXX?whatever)** >>>> **localhost:8443/ords/something:XXX?whatever**

I tried the following configuration but it's not working.

- When I type **[www.example.com/ords](http://www.example.com/ords)** I'm getting only Case B : **localhost:8443/ords/something:ORDS** (while I'm expecting Case A : **localhost:8443/ords**)

Can any one help please ?

```
    server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name example.com www.example.com;
            
            location = /ords {
                            proxy_set_header Host $host;
                            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/ords;                             
                            }
                        
            location / {
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/ords/something:;
                            }                               
    }
```

Comment: Seems to be a re-post of [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65964817/how-to-reverse-proxy-in-nginx-with-suffix). Did you try posting it to the correct site, as suggested?

Comment: @costaparas, If you have an answer then thank you, otherwise let the check of which question is relevant to administrators

Comment: I am suggesting to post on a different site, since its unlikely this sort of question will get answered here (it is in fact [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Of course, you're welcome to keep it here, if you prefer.